# DocPad v6.57.0 - Failed to load/Unable to parse

Tags: docpad

I am new to DocPad, and I was running the KitchenSink demo with no issues.

I then decided to follow the Beginner Guide on the DocPad website (no skeleton), and I am hitting a snag at "Installing the template engine" section.

I got this warning when I tried to run docpad. I get the warning even if I stop DocPad (ctrl+c) and restart it. I am on OSX.

```
info: Generating...
warning: Failed to load the file: /path-to-project/src/documents/about.html
The error follows:
warning: An error occured:
Unable to parse.
warning: Failed to load the file: /path-to-project/src/documents/index.html
The error follows:
warning: An error occured:
Unable to parse.
```

Answer (score 0):

Docpad throws this error when there is a malformed yaml file. For me it was a missing space between attribute and value. Instead of

```
---
keywords: "my keywords"
---
```

I had

```
---
keywords:"my keywords"
---
```